# How to correctly start a process in VC++?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I have a very simple window form program and I want to start notepad.exe when I press a button. I get some expected errors. Please help.

In the begining of my code, I have

```
#pragma once
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shellapi.h>
```

In the event handler, I have

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {


                //memset(&ExecuteInfo, 0, sizeof(ExecuteInfo));

                ExecuteInfo.cbSize       = sizeof(ExecuteInfo);
                ExecuteInfo.fMask        = NULL;              
                ExecuteInfo.hwnd         = NULL;               
                ExecuteInfo.lpVerb       = "open";                      // Operation to perform
                ExecuteInfo.lpFile       = "C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe";  // Application name
                ExecuteInfo.lpParameters = NULL;           // Additional parameters
                ExecuteInfo.lpDirectory  = NULL;                          // Default directory
                ExecuteInfo.nShow        = SW_SHOW;
                ExecuteInfo.hInstApp     = NULL;

                ShellExecuteEx(&ExecuteInfo);

         }
```

Note: I get the following the error message if I set to "Use Unicode Character Set" under property pages>Configuration Properties> General(ALT-F7)

```
1>c:\users\marco\desktop\new folder (2)\test000\test000\Form1.h(140): error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const char [5]' to 'LPCWSTR'
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>c:\users\marco\desktop\new folder (2)\test000\test000\Form1.h(141): error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const char [23]' to 'LPCWSTR'
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

Note: I get the following the error message if I set to "Use Multi-Byte Character Set" under property pages>Configuration Properties> General(ALT-F7)

```
1>test000.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000012) "extern "C" int __stdcall ShellExecuteExA(struct _SHELLEXECUTEINFOA *)" (?ShellExecuteExA@@$$J14YGHPAU_SHELLEXECUTEINFOA@@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall test000::Form1::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@Form1@test000@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>test000.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" int __stdcall ShellExecuteExA(struct _SHELLEXECUTEINFOA *)" (?ShellExecuteExA@@$$J14YGHPAU_SHELLEXECUTEINFOA@@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall test000::Form1::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@Form1@test000@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\New folder (2)\test000\Debug\test000.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution: If you are using C++/CLI, you can just as well use the managed method to start a process:

```
System::Diagnostics::Process::Start("C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe");
```

That should also avoid the character set problems.
Which doesn't mean you should ignore them as it's good to know about the underlying issue. Roee Shenberg adressed that in his answer.

Comment: I love this so much. I can open firefox and go to a website with just 1 line of code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the TEXT() macro around your strings (e.g. TEXT("open") instead of "open") or convert your ANSI strings to UTF-16 at runtime (for example, using the mbstowcs_s() function).

The reason this happens is that TCHAR is a Microsoft char type which is either char or wchar_t depending on whether the project is configured for unicode or not. Notice that the type of lpFile and friends is LPCTCHAR (long pointer to const TCHAR), meaning that if you're using the (default) unicode config, it ends up being a const wchar_t*, and a char[] can't be implicitly cast to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I followed what you said to change the "open" to TEXT("open"), also changed the notepad string to TEXT("c:\\windows\\notepad.exe"). I visited the properties page again and **changed back to the "Use Unicode Character Set"**. After that I tried to rebuild my program, but VS showed me the 1>test000.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000012) "extern "C" int __stdcall ShellExecuteExA(struct _SHELLEXECUTEINFOA *)" (?ShellExecuteExA ............. **(The same error as "Use Multi-Byte Character Set" setting)** Any suggestion?